# imapliy.error:[AUTHENTICATION FAILED) Invalid credentials (Failure)

Tags: python, imaplib

Good day everyone . I need help with my coding.
I'm using imaplib to login into gmail to send and receive messages

The code

Import imaplib

message = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com)

message.login('username', 'password')

After this ,I run the code to check if there's no problem .

But it raised an error  saying

imapliy.error:[AUTHENTICATION FAILED) Invalid credentials (Failure)

My logins are correct

I enabled imap on my gmail,still same error

I was expecting the code will run through successfully

Comment: You generally cannot log into Gmail with a password.  You need to implement OAuth2 or possibly generate and use app specific passwords.

Comment: Can you give me an example . I should add a code that implement OAuth2 . Can you please some time and gradually teach me the way out of it

Comment: I cannot; this is not a code writing service, and it's not just a few lines.  You can start here, `https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2?hl=en`  You will have to register an app, get an oauth2 library, etc.  However also note that Google is extremely picky about authorizing new applications for email as they consider email extremely private information and may require code audits.

Comment: Thank you Max . I will go through the process. Can we stay in touch please just for guidelines. And can you introduce me to code writing services to cooperate with more developers